# SQL Format numbers to have brackets

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to format a negative number to have brackets in SQL and positive numbers to appear as standard.

For example it currently shows a positive as 399 and a negative as -399 when I need a positive to show as 399 and a negative as -399.

This is for SQL Server 2005.

I have written the following for testing which is working.

```
SELECT num, CASE
    WHEN num < 0 THEN '(' + CAST(-num AS VARCHAR(11)) + ')'
    ELSE CAST(num AS VARCHAR(11))
END AS frmtd
FROM (
    SELECT    0 AS num UNION ALL
    SELECT  945        UNION ALL
    SELECT -945
) tests
```

However as you can see my Column name is just num but on the query I am trying to implement it there is a calculation happening.

This is the line:

```
SUM (PMC.[Net Sales] - PMCLY.[Net Sale LY]) / 1000  'Var Vs LY £k'
```

Can someone help me work out how I can factor this to work. I know it should be done at presentation layer but I want it to be done out of SQL.

Comment: replace all instances of `num` with `SUM (PMC.[Net Sales] - PMCLY.[Net Sale LY]) / 1000` or put `SUM (PMC.[Net Sales] - PMCLY.[Net Sale LY]) / 1000 as num` inside a sub query and `CASE WHEN num ...` in outer query (the code you posted alredy uses the sub query idea).

Answer (score 1):

Make a scalar function to use every time

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
CREATE FUNCTION FormatBracket(@Value as money)
RETURNS varchar(30)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RETVAL AS varchar(30);
    select
         @retval = case when @VALUE < 0 THEN 
                                    '(' + cast(ABS(@value) as varchar(28)) + ')'
                      else
                                    cast(@value as varchar(28))
                    END;

    RETURN @RETVAL;     

END
GO
```

then

```
SELECT num, dbo.FormatBracket(num)
AS frmtd
FROM (
SELECT    0 AS num UNION ALL
SELECT  945        UNION ALL
SELECT -945
) tests
```

I used the MONEY variable type, that can be any numeric type of course, I'm not sure Money was in 2005

Comment: Simple and reusable. Probably the best option for SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this work?

```
SELECT num,
       (CASE WHEN (SUM(PMC.[Net Sales] - PMCLY.[Net Sale LY]) / 1000)  < 0
             THEN '(' + CAST(-(SUM(PMC.[Net Sales] - PMCLY.[Net Sale LY]) / 1000) AS VARCHAR(11)) + ')'
              ELSE CAST((SUM(PMC.[Net Sales] - PMCLY.[Net Sale LY]) / 1000) AS VARCHAR(11))
        END) AS frmtd
```